# React-Native-Vector-Icons error on build

Tags: react-native

I have installed React Native Vector Icons, but it fails on build when i run "react-native run-android", with this error:

> startup failed:
>     build file 'C:\projects\musicapp\android\app\build.gradle': 3: unexpected token: apply @ line 3, column 1.
>        apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
>        ^

Comment: Did you link react-native-vector-icons with 'react-native link react-native-vector-icons' command?

Comment: Thank you. This solved the issue. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Installation:**

```
npm install --save react-native-vector-icons
```

**For Automatic link (RN < 0.60)**

```
react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

**For Manual setup**

**Edit `android/app/build.gradle` ( NOT `android/build.gradle` ) and add the following:**

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

**Run the project to test the installation.**

```
react-native run-android
```

**Import the library.**

```
import Icon from ‘react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome’
```

**Use it inside JSX. Text styles are welcome to be applied. Below is an example using also separated grid.* styling file.**

```
<View>
   <Icon name='area-chart' color="green" size={20} />
   <Text>Enjoy Coding.</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working now but the icons don't display. It shows an envelope icon flipped vertically.

Comment: if it is helpful then please upvote and tick the answer as correct

Comment: Try my example if icon doesn't display.

Comment: Thanks. They are displaying now.... You're a great man. You will live long and prosperous.

Comment: Pardon me @Dinesh Katwal but I don't have enough rep to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

***react-native >=0.60***

step:1  yarn add react-native-vector-icons

step:2 Add **apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"**  in (android/app/build.gradle)

step:3 cd android in cmd

step:4 ./gredlew clean

step:5 react-native run-android

step:6 import Icon from ‘react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome’