# Error : react-native-vector-icons:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. React-Native

Tags: android, react-native

I'm new into react-native and I've cloned one repo and setup project in my system now i'm tryingto run in android.

react-native run-android

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-vector-icons:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_111 contains a valid JDK installation.[image]

I've also tried installing vector icons using below link
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45569034/react-native-vector-icons-error-on-build)

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291056/could-not-find-tools-jar-please-check-that-c-program-files-java-jre1-8-0-151-c

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291056/could-not-find-tools-jar-please-check-that-c-program-files-java-jre1-8-0-151-c

you need jdk not jre

Answer (score 1):

this may help you :

you should added `JDK` path `org.gradle.java.home=C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_161` to `gradle.properties` file and rebuild your project.